# Why are the transparent regions of an image appear white in Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm exporting a png with transparent background:
[image]
This is how it looks when it's exported:
[image]
and this is how it is displayed in Tkinter:
[image]

My code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import customtkinter

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x480")
root.resizable(False, False)
background_black = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="background_black.png")
turn_on = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="turn_on.png")

tk.Label(root, image=background_black).pack()

button = tk.Button(root, image=turn_on, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0, relief=tk.FLAT)
button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.CENTER)

root.mainloop()
```

The regions that were supposed to be transparent are instead white, how can I fix this?
I presented the first 2 pictures in case I did something wrong on export and not in my code.

Comment: Note that tkinter widget does not support transparent background, so the gray part is the background of the button.

Comment: Is there any alternative to tkinter that is able to display transparency correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`tkinter.Canvas()`](https://www.google.com/search?q=tkinter.Canvas):

```
import tkinter as tk

def img_button_press(*args, **kwargs):
    print("Pressed")

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("512x512") 
root.resizable(False, False)

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=512, height=512)
canvas.place(x=0,y=0)
background_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="bg.png")
canvas.create_image((255,255), anchor="center", image=background_image)

btn_img = tk.PhotoImage(file="img.png")
btn = canvas.create_image((255,255), anchor="center", image=btn_img)
canvas.tag_bind(btn, '<Button-1>', img_button_press)
tk.mainloop()
```

You can of course use PIL to adjust the images if needed, but you don't need to if you have the images exactly as you need them:

img.png:

[image]

bg.png:

[image]

Seems to work:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it's a viable solution.